# I have one edittext and button.when i clicked Button that Inserted item will display another Edittext?

Tags: android, xml, button, android-edittext

`Edittext(AmountPaid) and Button(Print).`

when i clicked print  then  amountpaid will display another Edittext(TotalAmount).
Each time calculate and display amount.
Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

```
 total=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText20);
 amountpaid=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);

Print.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String amntpaid=PaymentPaid.getText().toString();
        total.requestfocus();
  }

});
```

Comment: Cursor goes to totalamount.but Inserted amountpaid value will not reach total(Edittext).

Comment: What is your logcat showing? Do post logcat error(if any).

Comment: @GrIsHu logcat is not showing any error. I am using total.requestfocus(); even cursor reach in total(edittext) but inserted amount how to display ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

you have to set the text for `EditText` like `total.setText(amntpaid);`

```
Print.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String amntpaid=PaymentPaid.getText().toString();
        total.requestfocus();
        total.setText(amntpaid);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
 total.setText(PaymentPaid.getText().toString().trim());
  total.requestfocus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your click listener code as below to show text in `EditText`:

```
    String amntpaid=PaymentPaid.getText().toString();
    total.setText(amntpaid);
    total.requestfocus();
```